# Xamarin list to manipulate items

Tags: xamarin.forms

I am new to Xamarin forms and looking for a control to list items. I would like to add/remove/update items with datasource or without a data source. I suppose ListView is what i am looking for. I am looking for an option to add/remove items from list from code behind. So far I tried to do it in manuall approach like below. I named control "Lista" to be able to reference to it from code behind. This way I added items directly but I would like more like to fill it by using from code behind like. `Lista.Add("something")` and `Lista.Remove("something")` nevertheless I haven't found the option. Please of sample advice. I would also appreciate sample when list data is coming from datasource.

```
 <ListView x:Name="Lista">
            <ListView.ItemsSource>
                <x:Array Type="{x:Type x:String}">
                    <x:String>mono</x:String>
                    <x:String>monodroid</x:String>
                    <x:String>mononucleosis</x:String>
                </x:Array>
            </ListView.ItemsSource>
        </ListView>
```

**Bonus question:**
Is there a control that could handle two columns data?

Comment: To add or delete items you have to use the ObservableCollction<Object> then the changes will reflect to listview

Comment: @KK Thanks. And how to bind it for example to datatable?

Comment: use this link for reference [link] https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/listview/data-and-databinding

Answer (score 0):

you can do something like this:

// cretate an observable collection

```
ObservableCollection<your_object_type> observableCollection = new ObservableCollection<your_object_type>();

observableCollection.Add(your_object);

Lista.Itemsource = observableCollection ;
```

then you can use data binding within XAML to bind to what ever property your_object has this way :

```
<ListView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <TextCell Text="{Binding your_object_property1}" Detail="{Binding your_object_property2}"/>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListView.ItemTemplate>
    </ListView>
```

Answer (score 0):

For doing that, there are two possible approaches. First, you set the `Lista.ItemSource` to an `IEnumerable`, like a list of strings. Then, every time you change this list, you must "update" `Lista.ItemSource`, that's basically that:

```
private void RefreshList()
{
    Lista.ItemsSource = null;
    Lista.ItemsSource = your_list;
}
```

I'm not a big fan of this approach, but it works.

Another option is to use an `ObservableCollection`, like an observable collection of strings and set it to `Lista.ItemsSource`:

```
// MyList is a property. That's global, so you can access from other methods.
MyList = new ObservableCollection<string>
{
    "String 1", "String 2", "String 3"
};
Lista.ItemsSource = MyList;
```

Then, every time you add, remove or update your list, the ListView is going to be updated automatically. That's the best approach.